# Fuzzy Matching, Confidence Score, C#

Tags: c#, similarity, fuzzy

I'm trying to calcuate the confidence score that a string appears within a subset of a much larger set.

Say I have 10 words in my original list and I match a new word against all 10 words.  Each match returns a similarity score.  I've set a threshold to ignore any similarity score that is below 70%.  So at the end I'm left with my input word possibly matching 3 words within my list.

To me this gives me 33.333% chance that my input word is a match against the 3 words with the higher similarity score.  I want to calculate how confident I am that the word is a match is these three.  I've calculated my confidence score as follows but this seems wrong and way to simple.

1. Cat 1 - 70% similarity - 33.3% chance.
2. Cat 2 - 75% similarity - 33.3% chance.
3. Cat 3 - 80% similarity - 33.3% chance.

((0.70) * (0.333)) + ((0.75) * (0.333)) + ((0.80) * (0.333)) = 75% Confident.

What is the best method of calculating confidence levels?

EDIT: Better Sample as requested

Original Word Set

1. Hello
2. Help
3. Hell
4. Problem
5. World
6. Ocean
7. Animal
8. Carrot
9. Brown
10. Black

Match New Word - Helicopter against original word set.
The match returns 3 words from the original set with a similarity score of over 70%.  The words returned were:
1. Hello - Similarity 70%
2. Help - Similarity 75%
3. Hell - Similarity 80%

I want to calcuate score that show how confident I am that helpicopter is a match to the words returned.

Answer: at [link] http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/ff9fc38e-8ca3-4d9a-b505-dfbe37910b17

Comment: Could you post the original problem? There isn't much sense into what you're trying to do without any info.

Comment: Depending on your similarity check algorithm, assuming that it will return 100% only if it matches, then the probability is obviously 100% if at least one similarity is 100%, and 0% otherwise. Maybe what you're trying to calculate is "how good my similarity check algorithm is"?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate how confident I am that my word belongs in either category returned with a similarity score above the set threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your probabilities are not right (or are not probabilities). You seem to have assumed that your word **is** a match for one of the top three similarity scores (if it is, your confidence level is *de facto* 100%...). Also, the probability and similarity scores are not independent, so your calculation is also flawed if you're looking for anything that has a basis in probability/statistics.

What you have actually done is work out the **mean** "similarity" for the top three cases. If that's acceptable as your (non-statistical) confidence level, then that's fine. But you're going to have to make a value call on this yourself - there's no mathematical basis really to what you are trying to do. To help further, you'll have to give us a lot more information on:

- How your similarity score is calculated.
- What the probability is that your word matches something in the list of 10 to start with.
- How similar are the 10 words in your list.
- etc. etc.

---

**Edit following your edit:**

Your three "similarity" scores are far from indepdendent, because the three words themselves are very "similar". And in any event, any algorithm that says "helicopter" is 80% similar to "hell" is not very good. I'd say the confidence level is pretty close to zero in this case....!

Comment: I'm using Jaro Winkler to calculate the similarity.  The similarity and confidence score are two different things.  The similarity score provides the answer as to how similar the words in the list are to my input word.  The aim is to produce an ssis component that will return a confidence and similarity score on fuzzy matching.  Very similar to the fuzzy grouping ssis component.  SQL Server 2012 doesn't come witht he Fuzzy Lookup component unless you invest in the enterprise edition which my company are unwilling to do.  Hence this project.

Comment: The Jaro distance between "hell" and "helicopter" is (hand calculation) 0.683. With the prefix scale included (i.e. the Jaro-Winkler distance), with standard factor, I make this 0.7781. OK, that's fairly close to 80%. Now look at the words. Do you think these words are 80% similar? Also, what exact interpretation are you giving to "confidence level" in this case?

Comment: The above is only an example. I've been recommended to use Bayesian probability. To calculate the probability/confidence score.  I want to calculate how confident I am that the word belongs in either of the 3 matches.  To me its simple 33.3% confidence of going into either.  I've been told that this is too simple though.

Comment: So you are looking for a probability measure of some sort. The problem is, Jaro-Winkler distance is not a probability measure, so it can't really form part of your calculations. Neither, for that matter, can the SQL Server implementation. Can you define what you mean by "match" in this example; what exactly is your desired end result, in context?

Comment: I'm trying to fuzzy group strings.  The Fuzzy grouping ssis component uses a similarity score and a condfidence score to fuzzy group inputs together.  It uses the jaro winkler algorithm for the similarity, I'm not sure what it uses for the confidence but I've been advised that it's most likily the bayesian probability theorum.

Comment: OK, but Bayesian probability is related to combining non-independent probabilities (i.e. conditional probabilities). It has no use when applied to an arbitrary "similarity" figure which is not a probability. So that advice is wrong. Your grouping may be a "fuzzy" grouping, but your understanding of the grouping criteria needs not to be fuzzy if you're going to be able to tell us enough to help you here I'm afraid.

Comment: I've found this "The confidence score is a measure of how likely it is that a particular value is the best match among the matches found in the reference table." taken from [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137786).  Looking at this I think I understand how to calculate the confidence and it looks like the simple sample I gave above is the correct way to calculate it.

Comment: No it's not, sorry. "How likely" = "Probability". "Similarity" != "Probability". That's your problem in a nutshell...

Comment: I should reiterate that even if your similarity measure **was** a probability, your calculation would be flawed, because you have restricted to the top three matches and assume all to be equally likely candidates. A more likely probability of your word matching one in the list, if similarity = probability, would be `1 - (1 - p1)(1 - p2)(1 - p3)...`. But even this assumes independence, which is not there in your case (_c.f._ hell/help/hello).

Comment: Following the example, in the case that there is only one word with a distance above 70% (let's say with a similarity of 78%) you are saying that you are 78% confident that it is a match for your word. If that is the result you are expecting then it's ok...

Comment: What if I returned two words with a similarity above 70%?  How would I calculate the confidence then?

Comment: You can't. Please see my earlier comments. Tallmaris is right, but you have to read what he's actually written: "**If that is the result you are expecting** then it's OK". But in your case, you want your confidence level to be **probabilistically based**, and **it simply isn't** based on a simple Jaro-Winkler distance. You would need a way to translate your similarities into probabilities, and to fully understand the dependencies between these probabilities, to go anywhere. And you're not going to be able to achieve this. You simply are not going to be able to find a mathematical confidence...

Comment: ...level based on this. All you can do is take these distances as relative measures, try some algorithms to make a yes/no decision, and see which work(s) for you.